# Не могу понять, почему не работает (я новичок)

Tags: java, циклы

```
package net.ukr.vladsemenov;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[] { 9, 4, 5, 76, 3, 21 };
        System.out.println(maxNumber(a));
    }

    static int maxNumber(int[] a) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i += 1]) {
                max = a[i];
            } else {
                max = a[i += 1];
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что у вас индекс цикла меняется в самом теле цикла `i+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что бред.

```
static int maxNumber(int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: чтобы не гадать нужны отрицательны числа или нет, достаточно начальный максимум(минимум) задать равным нулевому элементу массива и начать обход с первого.

Comment: @rdorn исправил. но для этого думать надо. а с этим проблема. тогда как сидя в ide можно быстро вспомнить где там это minValue, что бы я и сделал даже если в данном случае не нужны)

Answer (score 0):

Для  а[i += 1] нужно сначала проверить, не выходит ли индекс за границу массива. Да и писать подобным образом не стоит.
можно так сделать:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = new int[] { 9, 4, 5, 76, 3, 21 };
    System.out.println(maxNumber(a));
}

private static int maxNumber(int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i : a) {
        if (max < i) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Кстати, можно это сделать проще.
Либо через лист, либо через stream:

```
int max = Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас некорректно задан цикл.

В строке `if (a[i] > a[i += 1])` вы изменяете значение i на 1, чего вам делать не нужно, так как вы хотите обратиться к следующей ячейке.

Правильно вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
            max = a[i];
        } else {
            max = a[i + 1];
        }
```

И обратите внимание, что цикл пробегает до `a.length-1` во избежание нарушений границ массива.